# A problem about using MPI_Send

Tags: c, mpi

I'm learning MPI_Send, but I'm confused about this method. I wrote a simple pingpong program which the rank-0 node send the message to rank-1 node, and then the latter one returns a message to the former one.

```
if (rank == 0) {   /* Send Ping, Receive Pong */
  dest = 2;
  source = 2;
  rc = MPI_Send(pingmsg, strlen(pingmsg)+1, MPI_CHAR, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  rc = MPI_Recv(buff, strlen(pongmsg)+1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);
   printf("Rank0 Sent: %s & Received: %s\n", pingmsg, buff);
  }
else if (rank == 2) { /* Receive Ping, Send Pong */
  dest = 0;
  source = 0;
  rc = MPI_Recv(buff, strlen(pingmsg)+1, MPI_CHAR, source, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &Stat);
  printf("Rank1 received: %s & Sending: %s\n", buff, pongmsg);
  rc = MPI_Send(pongmsg, strlen(pongmsg)+1, MPI_CHAR, dest, tag, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
  }
```

I run this program on a 3 nodes environment. However, the system displays:

```
Fatal error in MPI_Send: Other MPI error, error stack:
MPI_Send(173)..............: MPI_Send(buf=0xbffffb90, count=10, MPI_CHAR, dest=2, tag=1, MPI_COMM_WORLD) failed
MPID_nem_tcp_connpoll(1811): Communication error with rank 2: Unknown error 4294967295
```

I'm wondering why I can send a message from rank-0 node to rank-1 node, but an error occurs when changed from rank-0 node to rank-1 node? Thanks.

Comment: You're running this with something like mpiexec -np 3 your-program-name?   What happens when you run mpiexec -np 3 hostname ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually have you checked whether strlen(pingmsg) is the same in both MPI_SEND and MPI_RECV

The amount of data sent using MPI_SEND should be less than or equal to the amount of data to be received by MPI_RECV or else it will lead to an error.

Comment: Thanks, actually, there was a problem of configuration on the cluster.